# How to statically access a .resx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, resx

Currently I access my resource .resx file like this:

```
ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager("Resources.Messages", Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
        string test = manager.GetString("EmailBodyMagazine", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

I'm trying to create a static class MessageResource that accesses the resource file so that to call this class from any code all I need to do is this:

```
string test = MessageResource.EmailBodyMagazine
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just look at any .NET framework assembly and see how they handle (error) strings.

Comment: The assembly where you are using the .resx, references App_GlobalResources? What Visual Studio version do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the .resx file using VS2008. From the .resx editor toolbar change the 'Access Modifier' to 'Public'. This will allow access to the resources from any asssembly that references the App_GlobalResources assembly (ex: Messages.EmailBodyMagazine).

You can also find a quick tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Localizing_ASP_NET_MVC.aspx).

Comment: Great thanks that did it although 'Access Modifier' was greyed out but if you change the Custom tool in the .resx properties to PublicResXFileCodeGenerator then it allows for the change